# If else with same code, but different condition

Tags: php, if-statement

I have got an if/elseif statement, both with the exact same code, but I want to trigger them depending on the condition. I have got the exact same code duplicated in the if statement aswell as the elseif statement.

```php
$x = 10;
$y = 20;

if ($x <= $y) {
    // some code
}
elseif ($x >= $y) {
    $oldX = $x;
    $x = $y;
    $y = $oldX;
    // same code as if
}
```

I am curious if there is a way that I do not have to duplicate my code in both the if statement aswell as the elseif statement.

Comment: Just `if($x >= $y){ $x = $y; $y = $x; }`, and the rest of the code you want to execute in any case simply _after_ that, without being wrapped in any if/else …?

Comment: @treyBake The problem is that with both the if aswell as the elseif I have got the same code, but just a very small difference. when the elseif is executed $x and $y should change and then the exact same code should be executed. I don't know if there is an easy way to do that without having to duplicate the code.

Comment: If $x == $y then both the if and the else is true

Comment: @Andreas Yes I know, I have got it a little bit different in my own code, but it was just an example for how the code should work. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I see it, you have two ways of going about this.

Alternative one: Create a function

```php
$x = 10;
$y = 20;

function myCodeBlock($x, $y) {
    // some code
}

if ($x <= $y) {
    myCodeBlock($x, $y);
} else {
    myCodeBlock($y, $x);
}
```

Alternative two (probably the most preferable): Put the codeblock *after* the check where you mix up the values of the variables.

```php
$x = 10;
$y = 20;

if($x >= $y){
    $oldX = $x;
    $x = $y;
    $y = $oldX;
}
// some code
```

Keep in mind, that by doing

```php
elseif($x >= $y){
    $x = $y;
    $y = $x;
```

...then `$y` and `$x` become equal - as you set `$x` to the value of `$y`, but then set `$y` back to `$x`, which was `$y`.

Comment: The first suggestion can be further simplified to `if ($x <= $y) { myCodeBlock($x, $y); } else { myCodeBlock($y, $y); }`. The second condition is always true if the first doesn't hold, and the $y assignment is a no-op.

Comment: Regarding your last part about $x and $y. I think the code should be: https://3v4l.org/id3MX

Comment: @Qirel Thank you for your fast reply, I got my code working. I have got the $x and $y a little bit different, but it was just an examply, But thanks for the fast reply ^^

Comment: @Andreas, `$x = $y; $y = $x;` is the same as `$x = $y;`. The second assignment does nothing.

Comment: I know. Don't you think it's to swap the values as my link above here shows?

Comment: @Andreas, yes, probably. Hence the comment in the code.

Comment: As the OP stated, he's not using `$x` and `$y` the same way, it was merely an example to simplify the question.